# jsPDF - addHTML function crashes chrome

Tags: google-chrome, crash, jspdf, html2canvas

We are trying to create a single page pdf , with a large html element, which is longer than the paper's length, and the chrome crashes. we tried changing the div's length and then adding the html a bunch of time so it would not have to process the entire div at once , but the function still processes the entire div even if it's invisible in the screen and in the final pdf result . Is there a way to tell the function to process only the visible dom elements so it wouldn't have to work so hard all at once?
here is the adding html to the pdf part of the code. we established a height of 2000px as an ok height - so for each div we calculate : DivTotalheight / 2000 = numOfImages . DivHeight = 2000px;

```
// the split image function
splitImage = function((doc, currImage,numOFImages,sumToNow , pageHeight, pageWidth,DivHeight){

    // check that this is not the last image
    if(currImage < numOfImages){
        // if this is the first crop , change the div's height to a relatively small height so the function could //process it quickly and doesn't crash
        if(currImage == 0)
        {
        MyDiv.height = MyDiv.height / numOfImages + 'px';
        }
        // pull the content of the div up (picture the content as a long toilet paper and we can only add a single piece at a time so each time we have to pull it up so we can see the next piece)
        MyDiv.marginTop = (currImage==0) ? 0 : -(sumToNom + DivHeight * currImage) + 'px';

        // add the current piece to the pdf and recursively continue to add the rest of the pieces
        doc.addHTML(MyDiv,0,pageHeight*currentImage/numOfImages, {formaty:'PNG',dim:{w:pageWidth,h:pageHeight/numOfImages}},function(){splitImage(doc, ++currImage,numOFImages,sumToNow + scrollHeight, pageHeight, pageWidth,DivHeight)})
    }
    // this is the last page and we need to save the pdf
    else{
        doc.save('doc.pdf');
    }
}
```

This code works , the result is a single page pdf with a number of images although it appears as only one long image. but it still takes forever or crashes, even though when we process a div that it's total height is 2000px it only takes a few seconds.. after hours of debugging we think maybe it has to do with the renderQueue and that it adds all elements even if not visible but we couldn't figure out how to make it process only the visible elements. the problem may also lie in the html2canvas..